# Can i insert the value in the php include function?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I already have this code for showing the country list:

```
<label><div>Country</div>
<?php include('includes/countrylist.php'); ?> 
</label>
```

and also have data of the country like this `$tourdetail['country']`.

So, how to show the value of the country in input box?

Sample code for input box:

```
<?= form_input(array('name' => 'country', 'value' => $tourdetail['country'])); ?>
```

Comment: I actually made a php file with all includes and then just include that single file whenever you need it.

Comment: @cyberoot You means you want input box into the include function?

Comment: Yes Bro,Do you know how to fixed this problem.? @SetKyarWaLar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, You can't bro. You can't put input box into `include` function. You need to use `include` and input separately. If you just want country with drop down so you can try like the following.

```
<?php
 include('includes/countrylist.php');

 foreach ($tourdetail['country'] as $country) {
   echo "<option value='". $country ."'>". $country ."</option>";
 } 
?>
```

Comment: It all depends what's in the included file. If a full selectbox or inputfields are in the included file, this IS possible!

Answer (score 1):

In your example i think you are using $tourdetail['country'] inside any function which you wrote in includes/countrylist.php. so re declare the variable like this inside your function.

global $tourdetail;

```
<?php 
    //declare a variable before including
    $temp="test";
    ?>
    <label><div>Country</div>
    <?php include('includes/countrylist.php'); ?> 
    </label>


    includes/countrylist.php
    ...
    global $temp; //if you are using inside any function make it as global
    echo $temp;
    ...
```

This $temp variable will be accessible inside your countrylist.php

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I understood that you would like to display the country values in dropdown box.

Please find the below code:

In your include file, you already defined your country list as an array list "$tourdetail['country']".

```
<select name="country">
<?php
 include('includes/countrylist.php');

 foreach ($tourdetail['country'] as $country) {
   echo "<option value='". $country ."'>". $country ."</option>";
 } 
?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see this

```
<input name="country" type="text" class="text_box" required id="country" value="<?=isset($tourdetail['country']!=''?$tourdetail['country']:'')?>" />
```

Comment: Please see this to learn how to format your posts correctly: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help